# Что происходит, когда пользователь вводит в браузере какой-нибудь сайт?

Tags: запрос, браузер

Можете в двух словах на пальцах объяснить, что происходит, когда пользоватеь вводит сайт в браузере и нажимает enter?
Куда какие запросы отправляются, что куда передаётся, как вообще определяется куда пользователь хочет зайти и т.д.

Comment: Интересный вопрос, если кто-нибудь полную схему распишет :)

Comment: @Qwertiy я бы даже его плюсанул!

Comment: @Qwertiy а может и сам напишу ответ, если найдётся свободный час)

Comment: @Suvitruf, меня вот часть про https и http2 интересует. По http я представляю (хотя есть некоторые нюансы, по которым есть сомнения), а вот с механизмом переключения на http2 и самим протоколом - ну прям очень поверхностно. Самому пока некогда написать простую версию.

Comment: @Qwertiy всё уже описано до нас https://habr.com/company/htmlacademy/blog/254825/

Comment: И отдельно про HTTPS https://habr.com/post/191954/ (а вот про http2 не встречал)

Comment: @andreymal, да, интересно. Надо будет обязательно прочитать.